# .DSK to .vdi or other Virtual box supported format

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, conversion, vdi, virtual-disk

Is there any way to convert dsk files to any usable format for virtual box? Is this type of conversion possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of virtual disk format .DSK is or how it was created but you can try to use VirtualBox'es [VBoxManage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) command (especially the [convertfromraw](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp59139136) subcommand) to convert your disk image to VDI/VMDK/VHD.

Comment: Thank you, it worked running the command "vboxmanage convertfromraw <.DSK location> <new .VDI location>"

Answer (score 0):

I found an old IDE hard drive with Windows 98 on it and had to follow several steps to get it running in VirtualBox in Windows 10 after running the command mentioned in the comments above.

Here was the full process that worked for me. You can skip to step 3 if you already have the DSK file.

1. Buy an IDE to USB adapter ([roughly $20 on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077N2KK27)) and use it to hook up the old hard drive to a modern Windows PC.
2. The filesystem on the disk probably won't be recognized by Windows, but it should be visible to a program like [DiskInternals Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/). Use a program like that to [dump the hard drive's contents to a DSK file](https://www.diskinternals.com/create-disk-imaging/).
3. [Install VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
4. Open Powershell in the DSK file's directory (or `cd` into it manually)
5. [Add VirtualBox to the system path:](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/vboxmanage-command-not-found-in-windows-cmd-or-powershell.html)

```
$env:PATH = $env:PATH + ";C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
```

6. Use VirtualBox's `vboxmanage` tool to convert the DSK file to a VDI file:

```
vboxmanage convertfromraw myoldharddrive.dsk myoldharddrive.vdi
```

7. Create a new virtual machine in VirtualBox. When prompted for a hard drive, select your newly created VDI file:

[image]

Using those steps, I was able to access the Windows 98 installation found on the hard drive, albeit with a few graphical issues that I still have to work out.

Comment: Thanks for the vboxmanage command, @FrancoisduPlessis